# Convert epoch time to SQL Server datetime and get the data of current date - 3

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This question has been asked several times on this forum. But I did not find a solution to this problem

```
select dateadd(ms, CAST (1430607256000 AS BIGINT), '1970-01-01 00:00:00.0');
```

I am trying to get this in human readable format. But I am getting the below error:

> [22003][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

I actually need the dates which is in between `current_date-3 00:00:00 and current_date-3 23:59:59`.

I am an `Oracle` person, new to `SQL Server`. Please help.

My `Oracle` query is:

```
SELECT TRIM(datecol)  
FROM transactions 
WHERE datecol BETWEEN (((TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE+INTERVAL '-3'DAY, 'DD MON YYYY')||' '||'00:00:00','DD MON YYYY HH24:MI:SS') - TO_DATE('1970-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')) * 86400000) + 14400000) AND (((TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE+INTERVAL '-3'DAY, 'DD MON YYYY')||' '||'23:59:59','DD MON YYYY HH24:MI:SS') - TO_DATE('1970-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')) * 86400000) + 14400000);
```

Comment: Which Sql server Version are you Using

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

First Change the `MilliSeconds` to `Minutes`(1430607256000/60000) and the Add it to the `Date` Value.

```
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE,1430607256000/60000,'1970-01-01 00:00:00.0');
```

**OutPut:**

```
2015-05-02 22:54:00.000
```